# Conjectures/Hypotheses which are stronger than Riemann hypothesis

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

I would like to ask what conjectures or hypotheses are present which are stronger than the original Riemann hypothesis i.e, if proven imply that the RH is true/false.

One example would be the [Merten's Conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture), which was thought to be stronger than the RH but was later disproven in 1985

Comment: If a conjecture is stronger than RH, disproving it means nothing as far as RH goes; Turan's conjecture about the finite partial sums of RZ is another such disproved stronger conjecture

Comment: Sorry, I meant if a particular conjecture is proven it'd imply RH true or false

Comment: outside GRH, various relatively conjectures about correlations of arithmetic functions like $\mu$ and various hypothesis on the distribution of zeroes of RZ, I am not aware of currently believed stronger conjectures (some forms of Mertens like $M(x)/\sqrt x$ bounded or $O(c(x))$ for some slow-growing $c$ are still stronger and not-disproved); there are many implications of RH that are thought to be strictly weaker (Lindelof, divisor problems, exponential sum estimates, momentum estimates) so obviously disproof of any such would disprove RH